# Proving $e^{-z}=\frac{1}{e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove $$e^{-z}=\frac{1}{e^z}$$.

Taking $z=z_1+z_2i$ then:

$e^{-z}=e^{-(z_1+z_2i)}=e^{-z_1-z_2i}=e^{-z_1}.e^{-z_2i}$

I know the first part is easy to see $e^{-z_1}=\frac{1}{e^{z_1}}$ since $z_1$ is a real number.

However I am not seeing how to proceed with $e^{-z_2i}$.

**Question:**

Since I have the imaginary unit. How should I treat $e^{-z_2i}$?

Thanks in advance!|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $e^{z+w}=e^z\cdot e^w$ you get immediately
$$e^{z-z}=e^0 = 1\Rightarrow e^{-z} =\frac{1}{e^z}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:$$e^{-z_2i}=(e^{-z_2})^i, z_2\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: How do you prove $1^i=1$?

Comment: Simply write $1$ as $e^0$ and use De Moivre's formula.

Comment: The correct question would have been: How do you define $1^i$?

Comment: @Klaus           Got it! $1^i=\cos(\ln(1))+i\sin(\ln(1))=1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{}
e^{z_1} e^{z_2}&=\sum_{k_1=0}^\infty\frac{z_1^{k_1}}{k_1!}\sum_{k_2=0}^\infty\frac{z_2^{k_2}}{k_2!}=\sum_{k_1=0}^\infty\sum_{k_2=0}^\infty\frac{z_1^{k_1}z_2^{k_2}}{k_1!k_2!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{k_1=0}^k\frac{z_1^{k_1}z_2^{k-k_1}}{k_1!(k-k_1)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\sum_{k_1=0}^k\frac{k!}{k_1!(k-k_1)!}z_1^{k_1}z_2^{k-k_1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(z_1+z_2)^k}{k!}=e^{z_1+z_2}.\\
\end{array}
$$
Subsitute now $z_1=z$, $z_2=-z$.